# Crucial.com gives me 2 answers for memory?

Tags: memory

I went to crucial.com to determine what kind of memory I can upgrade from I currently have a gateway pc thats a couple years old, it has 2 memory slots, both filled with 512mb of PC2-4200 DDR2 ram

**1)**
I looked up my PC on Crucial here

http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=GT5428&pl=Gateway&cat=RAM

It says I can have a max of 2gb TOTAL, 1gb per slot on my PC.

**2)**
I then also used there tool that you download that scans your PC for possible memory.  When I did that, it shows I can have a total of 4gb of memory, 2gb per slot.

Now I would hope for the second option to be true but I am confused, it is saying I can only have 2gb, then it says 4gb so which is it?

Comment: I would suggest asking crucible. They are the only ones that will know exactly how their tool works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that site is all well and good, but you should really be checking with your manufacturer (Gateway) first.. A quick search found your model's specs on their site:

> - Installed: 1024 MB DDR2, 533 MHz, (PC4200) dual channel memory (two 512
>     MB DIMMs)
> - Expandable to: 2 GB (two DDR2 DIMM slots)

You can install 2x1GB modules at PC4200.

Here's the [link](http://support.gateway.com/s/PC/R/1009466/1009466sp2.shtml).

Comment: Of course read manufacturers specs- but also note that sometimes a firmware upgrade or other factor can change things. I you have a convenient 2Gb stick to throw in there I say give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the scanner tool at [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com), you are guaranteed to get the correct memory - otherwise you get a full refund.

We rely on the scanner tool where we work for ordering additional memory in remote computers at clients and have never found it to be wrong (yet!)

Comment: Have you got a link for the refund claim?

Comment: Sure do.  http://www.crucial.com/support/crucialtop10.aspx

"Find the Right Memory with the Crucial Memory Advisor™ tool
We guarantee that the upgrades you find through the Crucial Memory Advisor tool will be compatible with your system, or your money back."

Answer (score 0):

I read this question after all of your other questions `:-)`.

Your Gateway system supports only DDR2 (so [the other question with DDR confusion](https://superuser.com/questions/32419/can-ram-with-a-higher-speed-work/32428#32428) is resolved).

Point 1 in this question.
The Gateway specifications seem to limit your system at 2GB (2x1GB).

Point 2.
The Crucial Scan tool has checked your current state (hardware and firmware) to confirm 
that you can actually work with 4GB (2x2GB) kits.

I think you can go with 4GB (like `ezwi` mentions here and in another answer).