# Mis matched memory?

Tags: memory

My PC currently has 1 gb of ram 2 512s, I am kinda stuck, I need as much memory as possible, crucial.com and gateway both sites say my PC can only handle 2gb TOTAL 1gb per slot but when I run the crucial.com scanner, it says my motherboard can andle 4gb total, 2gb per slot so I am kinda wanting to try the 4gb route but I am not possitive it will work so I was wanting to only purchase a 2gb stick at first.

So would a 2gb stick work with a 512mb next to it?  I would make sure they are the same speed, just different sizes.

I read the the scanner on crucial is pretty accurate so it's confusing whether 2gb or 4gb will work or not on my pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

too many 'maybe' and 'could be' for my taste. unless you post make and model of your mainboard and find a user here who has done it, you will not get a definitive answer at SU (or any other forum for that matter).

if you're not certain, bring your box to a local computer store (support your locals! :) and have it fitted. yes, they will charge you a little bit more but it's hasslefree and you'll have it done right away. ring 'em up and ask for quote, then decide whether it's worth it or not.

Comment: i don't want to discourage Jason from upgrading the memory. it's just if he wants to play it safe, then he should go with compaq's AND crucial's recommendation. if he wants to go experimental, he better be prepared buying memory that may not work or have it done at a local store in no time.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Crucial scanner, I believe you are guaranteed to get compatible memory - otherwise your money back.  Nothing to lose really.

> Find the Right Memory with the Crucial
>   Memory Advisor™ tool We guarantee that
>   the upgrades you find through the
>   Crucial Memory Advisor tool will be
>   compatible with your system, or your
>   money back.

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same speed, you *should* be fine.

It will perform better if they are the same size, density, CAS latency, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The GT5428 Crucial link you gave in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/29001/crucial-com-gives-me-2-answers-for-memory) says,

> you can install modules one at a time, and you can mix different densities of modules in your computer. But if your computer supports dual-channel memory configurations, you should install in identical pairs (preferably in kits) for optimal performance.

That answers this question.