# Can RAM with a higher speed work?

Tags: memory

I have the memory below and I am looking at using the one below it, would it be OK to use?  It appears to be a faster speed, is that OK?  Also, mine says PC 4200, the new one says PC **2** 5300 and the frequencies are different.

Currently I have: 1024 MB DDR2, 533 MHz, (PC4200) dual channel memory

Looking to get: KVR667D2/2GR DDR2 2 GB, 667 MHz/PC2-5300

Do you think this would work or not?  I know I could use [crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/) and stuff but I really want to buy something local today.

---

OK, I just realized on crucial.com this is my 1st result for a match, so I guess it should work.

Sorry for the confusion, the PC in question is a [Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway,_Inc.) GT5428 here is a link to the specs http://support.gateway.com/s/PC/R/1009466/1009466sp2.shtml

Comment: It would really help if you just included the motherboard model in this question.

Comment: I have updated with a link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will work although keep in mind the lowest common denominator will be used. In other words the new memory you put in will run at the same speed as the slower stick.

To check for compatibility [Crucial's Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx) is very good.

Comment: I plan on replacing the old memory, just wanted to make sure it would work though

Comment: Ah i thought you were mixing and matching

Comment: whether it may or may not work, it is pointless anyway' you wouldn't achieve any performance gain since your Gateway BIOS most certainly doesn't allow changing the memory speed. those spartan OEM BIOSes aren't made for overclockers. and you don't make anything sure here by asking theoretical questions in a forum without providing details for your computer/mainboard. we can only guess and this may not do you any good in the end. read my post in your original thread about 'supporting your locals. :)

Comment: Nobody said anything about performance gains, sometimes you just need more memory for your applications.

Answer (score 4):

Update: `John`'s inquisitive points made me look at the '`PC-4200`' part more closely.
I was wondering how DDR and DDR2 were being confused like this.
It is possible that the OP has PC-4200 confused and it is probably PC2-4200.
All this would be clearer if the motherboard model is listed for reference.

The line "*1024 MB DDR2, 533 MHz, (PC4200) dual channel memory*" also matches **PC2-4200**.
If that memory is PC2, he has a DDR2 board and Crucial confirming PC2-5300 works on it is good news for the OP.

---

First thing to understand, [DDR2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM) is different from older [DDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM).
From the DDR2 link,

> DDR2 SDRAM is a double data rate synchronous dynamic random access memory interface. It supersedes the original DDR SDRAM specification and the two are not compatible. In addition to double pumping the data bus as in DDR SDRAM, (transferring data on the rising and falling edges of the bus clock signal), DDR2 employs an I/O buffer between the memory and the data bus so that the data bus can be run at twice the speed of the memory clock. The two factors combine to achieve a total of 4 data transfers per memory clock cycle.

So, if you motherboard uses PC-4200 (DDR) memory, it is not likely to support PC2-5300 (DDR2) memory.

---

With DDR3 memory entering the arena fast -- and while DDR2 is still quite active,
we *do* have news of motherboards that will work DDR2 and DDR3 memory...
[MSI Unveils DDR2+DDR3 Combo Motherboard](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/MSi-Eight-Memory-Slots,7214.html).

[image]

> MSI showcased two amazing motherboards at CeBIT: its AM3 board 790GX-8D featuring the 790GX chipset, and its socket 775 board P45-8D using Intel's P45 +ICH10/ICH10R chipset. What makes these two boards so extremely hot is their huge memory capacity, both offering four DDR2 slots and four DDR3 memory slots. Nicknamed as the "Memory Lover," both utilize MSI's power saving technology APS as well as its "DrMOS" high quality voltage converters.
>
> Out of the two, **the 790GX-8D seems a bit more versatile**, compatible with AMD's AM3 processors with DDR2-1066 or DDR3-1333 RAM (using bypass) while also capable of supporting the AM2+ CPU with DDR2 RAM.
> **Up until now, you had to choose between DDR2 or DDR3, but not both.**

---

But, all that is for DDR3 and DDR2, I strongly suspect no such support is made for DDR and DDR2 -- and, if it is, you are unlikely to pick such a motherboard.

Choose your upgrade carefully.

Comment: I may be reading the question wrong, but why does everyone seem to think he's using DDR? There is no mention of it in the question. He already has DDR2 installed.

Comment: @John, because he says he has PC-4200 now and wishes to upgrade to PC**2**-5300. The first is DDR and the second is DDR2.

Comment: then underneath he writes "Currently have: 1024 MB **DDR2**, 533 MHz, (PC4200) dual channel memory "

Comment: I take it as a typo. Since he highlights the **2** earlier while talking about PC-4200 in the same breath.

Comment: All this would be easier if he just listed the motherboard model.

Comment: I goofed! That was before coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it usually works, because RAM usually is downwards compatible.

For example, your MoBo and CPU can only handle a DDR-2 PC4200 (533 Mhz), but you go and buy DDR-3 PC5300 (677MHz).

The new bought DDR-3 PC5300 (677MHz) will then be run as DDR-2 PC4200 (533 Mhz). You haven't won anything performancewise. You just have reservers until your new MoBo and CPU can handle DDR-3 PC5300 (677MHz) then the new RAM will run as this.

Usually you have to adjust settings in your BIOS.
.....